# route to another network Adapter

Tags: windows, routing, kerio

I have two network adapters. One is a wireless one that all my devices are connected to and the other is a virtual connection in my Windows 8.1 notebook.

I want to do something (port forwarding proxy server I think) so that when I use a proxy on another device with the IP of my notebook and a port of choice, the traffic passes through the virtual connection.

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[Port Mapper](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/network/pmapper/freeware.htm) might help, not sure if it can run as a service but it allows you to forward/route traffic to another port or another machine all together.